# Is there any way to hide first options of @react-native-community/picker?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, picker

```
I would like to hide my first options "Please select"
```

of picker item when pop up open, there should be show only label item
which i want to select not "please select" label, if anyone help please help, Thank You.

```
          <Picker 
          mode="dropdown"
          selectedValue={this.state.textInputData.state}
          onValueChange={(itemValueitemIndex)=>this.onChangeTextInput('state',itemValue)}>
            <Picker.Item value='' label='Please select state'  />
            <Picker.Item label="Abu Dhabi" value="Abu Dhabi" />
            <Picker.Item label="Dubai" value="Dubai" />
            <Picker.Item label="Sharjah" value="Sharjah" />
            <Picker.Item label="Ajman" value="Ajman" />
            <Picker.Item label="Umm Al-Quwain" value="Umm Al-Quwain"  />
            <Picker.Item label="Fujairah" value="Fujairah" />
            <Picker.Item label="Ras Al Khaimah" value="Ras Al Khaimah" />
          </Picker>
```

Comment: Can you provide some code and show us what you've tried?

Comment: @Auticcat yes i have edited my question please find above code, let me know if you have any answer for this, thankyou.

Comment: @Auticcat I want to hide 'please select state' label when picker is opened. how can i hide this label item when picker is opened. please help.

Comment: So basically, you want to show it before the user clicks on the picker component, but once you show the picker list you don't want it there?

Comment: @Auticcat exactly.

Answer (score -1):

use `selectedValue` props as a null to hide

```
 <Picker
  selectedValue={null}
 .../>
```

Comment: okay .. please share your code I will try to implement it on my machine

Comment: I have edited my question with code you can find above, thankyou.